# Popup not updating dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first chrome extension, but I'm having issues updating automatcally my popup.html, basically I have a background.js in my background.html where communicates with firebase and then I send a message to content_scripts app.js where I use to update my custom popup, until than everything works fine, the problem is when I pass the message data to my popup.html

app.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
        command: "popup_list",
        data: response.data
    }, (response) => {

    
    });
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {

 if(msg.command == "popup_list"){

    renderHtml(msg.data);
   
    
 }
      return true;
 
});
```

In my popup.js i receive the message, and I confirm when I right click in the popup.html and check on the console, my problem is that the popup.html is not updated automatcally. It only updates if I let the popup.html open and refresh the page, is there something that I'm missing out?

Comment: 1. do you receive the message correctly?

Comment: 2. can you change the popup without background page (message)?

Comment: do you get any error on console ? it feels like some permission or lt Content Security Policy error

Comment: The popup exists only when shown. It doesn't receive messages when it's hidden.

Comment: @GonzalesGokhan has i said, i receive the data with no problemns, the issue is the popup.html is not updated in the moment i click, the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener is fired after, i need to build the popup html data when is clicked before the user opens it.

Comment: You need to save the data in storage and read it when the popup opens. The popup doesn't see your messages when the popup isn't open.